# How can I make the position of the points on a map responsive

Tags: html, css, responsive

I would like to make the position of the red points on the map responsive. Does anyone have any idea how?

[image]
3 points
[image]
test1
[image]
test2
[image]
test3

---

**The HTML**

```
<div class="red_about_us_map">
  <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/a/a5/Map_of_USA_with_state_names.svg/750px-Map_of_USA_with_state_names.svg.png" />
  <div class="red_about_us_slogan">3 points</div>
  <div class="red_about_us_logo red_about_us_logo_it">
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/e5/Redpoint.svg"/>
  </div>
  <div class="red_about_us_text red_about_us_text_it">test1</div>
  <div class="red_about_us_logo red_about_us_logo_cz">
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/e5/Redpoint.svg"/>
  </div>
  <div class="red_about_us_text red_about_us_text_cz">test2</div>
  <div class="red_about_us_logo red_about_us_logo_de">
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/e5/Redpoint.svg" />
  </div>
  <div class="red_about_us_text red_about_us_text_de">test3</div>
</div>
```

**The CSS**

```
.red_about_us_map {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    position: relative;
}
.red_about_us_map img{
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    position: relative;
}
.red_about_us_logo_de {
    position: absolute;
    top: 95px;
    left: 245px;
}
.red_about_us_logo_it {
    position: absolute;
    top: 200px;
    left: 285px;
}
.red_about_us_logo_cz {
    position: absolute;
    top: 105px;
    left: 378px;
}
.red_about_us_logo_de img, .red_about_us_logo_it img, .red_about_us_logo_cz img {
    width: 70px;
}
.red_about_us_text_de {
    position: absolute;
    top: 168px;
    left: 198px;
    opacity : 0;
}
.red_about_us_text_it {
    position: absolute;
    opacity : 0;
    top: 273px;
    left: 237px;
}
.red_about_us_text_cz {
    position: absolute;
    top: 178px;
    left: 334px;
    opacity : 0;
}
.red_about_us_text {
    border: 2px solid #0093dd;
    width: 150px;
    color: #0093dd;
    font: normal bold 11px Gotham, Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    padding: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
    text-align: center;
    -webkit-transition: all linear 0.5s;
    -moz-transition: all linear 0.5s;
    -o-transition: all linear 0.5s;
    transition: all linear 0.5s;
}
.red_about_us_logo img {
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.5);
    -moz-transform: scale(0.5);
    -o-transform: scale(0.5);
    transform: scale(0.5);
    -webkit-transition: all linear 0.5s;
    -moz-transition: all linear 0.5s;
    -o-transition: all linear 0.5s;
    transition: all linear 0.5s;
    -moz-transform-origin: center;
    -ms-transform-origin: center;
    -o-transform-origin: center;
    -webkit-transform-origin: center;
    transform-origin: center;
}
.red_about_us_logo img:hover {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    -moz-transform: scale(1);
    -o-transform: scale(1);
    transform: scale(1);
    -webkit-transition: all linear 0.5s;
    -moz-transition: all linear 0.5s;
    -o-transition: all linear 0.5s;
    transition: all linear 0.5s;
}
.red_about_us_logo_de:hover + .red_about_us_text_de,   .red_about_us_logo_it:hover + .red_about_us_text_it, .red_about_us_logo_cz:hover + .red_about_us_text_cz {
    -webkit-transition: all linear 0.5s;
    -moz-transition: all linear 0.5s;
    -o-transition: all linear 0.5s;
    transition: all linear 0.5s;
    opacity : 1;
}
.red_about_us_slogan {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    border: 1px solid #0093dd;
    width: 300px;
    height: 50px;
    line-height: 24px !important;;
    color: #0093dd;
    font: normal bold 18px Gotham, Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    padding: 5px;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
    text-align: center;
    -webkit-transition: all linear 0.5s;
    -moz-transition: all linear 0.5s;
    -o-transition: all linear 0.5s;
    transition: all linear 0.5s;
}
```

You can see a working example in this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/taxishop/Lcer53kk/1/)

Comment: Position them with %age values rather than with absolute pixel values.

Comment: Thanx for the answer, but that is not very accurate, if you scale down the image you will see the point in other region than intended...

Comment: Added the code examples from jsfiddle, updated the title and tags and cleaned up some of the grammar.